# Can I use google,facebook etc. oauth in django-rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth

I want to implement oauth in my django-rest-framework project.I tried some packages but I'm getting errors everytime. If you have any idea please share with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using django allauth with it, its easy to implement facebook and other sites login
[docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html) and the example of the allauth [code](https://medium.com/@jinkwon711/django-allauth-facebook-login-b536444cbc6b)